# hidden any element in mobile view and show in medium view tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css

I need to hide a element in the mobile view and show to the same element in medium view.

I tried this,

```
<p classname="hidden md:visible">Hello</p>
```

But doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `md:block` instead `md:visible`

```html
<p class="hidden md:block">Text to hide on small screens</p>
```

But if you want to use `visible` you should use `invisible` instead of `hidden`.

```html
<p class="invisible md:visible">Text to hide on small screns</p>
```

You can check the difference here: https://www.thoughtco.com/display-none-vs-visibility-hidden-3466884

Answer (score 1):

By default, Tailwind uses a **mobile-first** breakpoint system, similar to what you might be used to in other frameworks like Bootstrap.

```
// case 1
<div class="hidden md:block"></div>

// case 2
<div class="invisible md:visible"></div>
```

Details:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#working-mobile-first